# Unable to run jmeter 4.0 script on Centos7

Tags: java, linux, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I am running jmeter 4.0 on my centos 7 system from command line but getting below error, please help.

JMeter command:-

```
./jmeter -n -t file_load.jmx -l loadResult.csv
```

Error:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxMetaspaceSize=256m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

java -version

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
openjdk version "1.8.0_161"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b14, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Is it reproduced with latest jmeter 4.0?

Comment: yes, m using 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you **really** run JMeter with Java 8, double-check which Java you're using via [`alternatives --config java`](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaRuntimeEnvironment) command

For instance I cannot reproduce your issue with Java 8 but with Java 7 it fails:

[image: JMeter Java 8]

As per [What’s New in JMeter 4.0?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) article you need to use at least Java 8 to run JMeter 4.0

Comment: :- Thanks, my problem got solved with older jmeter version, now m using jmeter 3.3